# Compare two columns in separate excel files and delete matching values via vba or batch file

Tags: excel, batch-file, vba

I have 2 excel files in one specific folder named as A.csv & B.csv.

There is a column Ref in excel file 'A' and Proj column in excel file 'B'

Ref column in excel A has numbers e.g.

```
9826218802031230101
9826218803031230101
```

and so as Proj Column in excel file B.

I want to compare these 2 columns in separate excel files via batch file or vba and create another excel file which will have all the values excluding deletion of any matching number between these 2 files of numbers which have '02' in the position 9 & 10 as above highlighted.

Comment: SO can help you to improve or edit your code to do what you want, but is not possible send you the complete code. Where you stopped? what you testing??

Comment: thanks Fabrizio for reply. I am looking for some suggestion what is the best way to do it. I am currently in the process of trying to write VBA executable snippet to do above.

Comment: ,first I will copy the two ranges in the new sheet, then with one loop I would check if in the new range some record have '02' in the digit 09-10 where is the record 02, If yes I delete the record. Try this code is not hard, any case we are here

Answer (score 0):

I'm not undestand wath you want, your question and your code haven't nothing in common. 
 anicase,
edit you code:
`For Each cell In Range("I2:I5" & lRow)` to `For Each cell In Range("I2:I" & lRow)`
and

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(cell.Row, "I"), Cells(cell.Row, "XX")).ClearContents
```

where xx is the column reference not one sheet